# Can I require a valid build before a pull request is merged on bitbucket

Tags: git, bitbucket

I want a git workflow where all changes are done on a branch and the developers have to create a pull request to merge into master.
The pull request needs to be approved by a reviewer and the build_must_be_successful.

Is that possible in bitbucket? I have seen it in Stash but would really like to avoid installing and maintaining a server.

If not. Is there another (free or paid) online git repository that supports that workflow?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

[Pull Requests](https://www.atlassian.com/git/tutorials/making-a-pull-request/how-it-works) are supported with Atlassian Git repos.

The classic model involves 2 repos (a fork and a main repo), but since BitBucket repos support [branch permissions](http://blog.bitbucket.org/2013/09/16/take-control-with-branch-restrictions/), you simply can:

- protect the master
- [make pull requests](https://confluence.atlassian.com/display/STASH/Using+pull+requests+in+Stash#UsingpullrequestsinStash-Creatingapullrequest) within the same repo

You also can enforce a [successful build for a pull request](https://confluence.atlassian.com/display/STASH/Checks+for+merging+pull+requests).

Comment: You wrote:  
"You also can enforce a successful build for a pull request."    
But the link points to the Stash manual. I am looking for exactly that but in bitbucket. Is that possible?

Comment: @user3656173 you would need a different approach like https://github.com/nishio-dens/bitbucket-pullrequest-builder-plugin

Comment: The problem with branch permissions though is that it means only 1 person/group can do the actual merge of the PR, and that one person can just as easily push to default/master from the command line.  So essentially it's restricted for everyone except that one user.